# Teamcity: Getting source using labelled version from TFS

Tags: build, tfs, continuous-integration, teamcity

How do I configure TeamCity to get changes from a labelled version from TFS?

In Teamcity

```
Administration
    Edit Build Configuration
        Edit VCS Root
```

Is this possible in the current version (v7)? I can't find an option for that.

Cheers

Comment: Are you sure that's a new feature in V7.1? If so, i might consider upgrading.

Comment: TC 7.1. can get changes using masks. Here is whatsnew http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/whatsnew/index.html

Comment: I upgraded but still can't work out how to achieve this.